# MS ACCESS/VBA - Using a form filter in docmd.runsql update query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform that the client is using the dropdown filter list on to search through 40k records.

I need to use the filter they selected in a line of code to update the select flag in the temporary table for only filtered records so they can append them to another table which acts as the list they are compiling. The recordset still has all 40k records so I need to just select what is displayed on the screen.

[image]

How can I use the filter in the code easily without doing a ton of instr and mid and manipulation? This is the filter in code:

([sfmJobSearch].[VerticalMarket] In ("AR - Amusement & Recreation","CO - Commercial","GO - Government"))

but I need it more like [verticalmarket] like "'*'AR - Amusement & Recreation'*'" (except with all the options not just one)

Any help would be great!

Comment: `in` is what you require, so, `where id in (1,2,3,4)` is the same as `where id =1 or id=2 or id=3 or id=4` so use what you have as the `where` in your SQL update, but replace `[sfmJobSearch]`

Comment: Temporary table? Append to new table? This sounds like unnecessary data duplication. The whole point of using a relational database is to eliminate data duplication through relations. If the user is compiling a list then there should be a list table that only contains IDs of selected entries in other tables. If the list table had only ListName and SelectionID columns you could then query select all entries by ListName and see all the things they selected. It would be a list view query.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following
1. in the table that is the subforms record source make  field property, a lookup, list box, with the option of allowing multiple values set to yes.

2. Then create an insert query to move data into the temporary table
3. the insert query will be like this
   INSERT INTO Table3 ( field1 )
   SELECT Table2.Field1.Value
   FROM Table2;

4  That will solve it, once the records as been moved into the temporary table,you can then use the values in the temporary table to update any other value in another table.

5. Place all the queries into a macro in the order that you want them to run.
6. I will suggest you have a delete query to delete all values in the temporary table first.before running the queries in 3.

The delete query should be the first query in the macro.